# Is there a guide or a published set of best practices to backup known configuration files in preparation of installing the OS?

Tags: system-installation, upgrade

Every time a new LTS appears I make the choice of upgrade or reinstall.  Upgrade is easy, but I like the idea of reinstalling the OS and clearing away any clutter or screwed up configurations.

Is there a guide or a published set of best practices to backup known configuration files in preparation of re-installing the OS or upgrading to a new LTS?

Backing up my home directory is easy, the issue is what else should I back up or make a note of.  For example, I typically make a list of what packages I installed so I can reinstall them.  I also make a backup of /etc so I can pick and choose files to update (network, sshd settings, etc), but I could use a list of configuration locations to make my life easier.  Does a list like this exist?

Comment: You seem a bit indecisive at the moment. you say that reinstalling the os can be good for you as maybe you have some screwed up configurations, great I agree this can be good! However you also wish to backup up you configuration files (possibly the screwed up ones) If you know which ones are screwed up then fix them and upgrade, if not then how will you know which files to backup? I don't think you can have it both ways. Unless I missed the point.. which is possible!!!

Comment: By screwed up configurations I meant cases where I built and installed something from source and then couldn't figure out how to uninstall it properly.  I'm o.k. with rechecking my config files for correctness, but I can't remember which config files to check. :)

Comment: Hmm I don't know if my two-cents is an "official guide" :p but whenever I do a full system backup I do `/` however I make sure to exclude `"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"` as these are populated at boot and `/lost+found` is filesystem specific.